# Does solr 4.6.1 work with php5?

Tags: php, solr, pecl

In the documentation of php-Apache Solr PHP extension, it is mentioned that "It is compatible with both versions 1.3 and 1.4 of Apache Solr." Does this mean that it isn't compatible with the newer versions?

Comment: I'm using version 3.6 (Ubuntu 13 default), and is working fine. Some of the newer features are not supported in the php solr extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** PECL Apache Solr extension 2.0.0b is now available at http://pecl.php.net/package/solr

The 2.x series are only for Apache Solr 4.x

Well, There are several incompatibilities with Solr Server 4.0 like commit/optimize parameters have changed + other incompatibilities. We are working on PECL Solr 2.0.0 for Solr 4+ @ https://github.com/php/pecl-search_engine-solr

It will be out soon, just need to update the documentation.

Comment: shall i use pecl release version 1.0.2(stable) or 2 which is a beta version??

Comment: version 2.0.0b is tested, however it introduces new functionalities, and some API changes and beta is done mostly so that people can try it and give feedback of any bugs or errors + so people can transition smoothly from the old API to the new one, so general rule, beta versions shall not be used in production.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It works. I am using solr with php5. you can check this [link](http://pecl.php.net/package/solr)
and install as given in document